# Detailed Int to String conversions in swift

Tags: swift, string, int

### What I need to do

I need to convert a two integers that I have into a String.

The first integer could be anything from 1-8, so is always 1 digit.
The second one is a 1 or two digit number.

For example, if I have 2 as the first Int and 8 as the second, I want the string, "208". If I have 2 and 12, then I want "212".

### What I currently have

```
print(Strig(Int1) + String(format: "%02d", Int2))
```

The problem is this gives me:

```
1-1
```

if the integers are 1 and 1, I want 101.

Comment: Your code does print "101" for the numbers 1 and 1.

Comment: Are you sure the second one is actually `1`? I'm nearly certain that it's `-1`. Anyway, `let s = String(format: "%d%02d", x, y)` should do the trick.

Comment: ... or `String(100*x + y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. How have you defined Int2? If it's `-1` then you'd get what you mention. If it's `1`, it should be 101:

```
let int1 = 1
let int2 = 1

print(String(int1) + String(format: "%02d", int2))
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right, the `Int` is `-1`. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. I just put this code in a playground and it worked perfectly:

```
let a = arc4random_uniform(9)
let b = arc4random_uniform(100)
let output = String(format: "%d%02d", a, b)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Int1 and Int2 declaration

```
let n1: Int = 1
let n2: Int = 1

let comb = String(n1) + String(format: "%02d", n2)        
print(comb)
```